# how to get rid of public from url in laravel 3

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, laravel

Hello I am new to laravel and i know laravel has new version but i am using version 3.

Now all i need to do is directly access `public` folder without typing `/pulic` in url.

I have placed below `.htaccess` file in `laravel` `root` but it giving me `404 error`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and i want to do this using `.htaccess` not using `virtualhost`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make your site's document root point to public from your server config (vhost on apache, not sure what it's called on nginx)